# Error in running an application which runs from network

Tags: network-shares, windows-server-2012

I am using a portable chat application via LAN which is placed in local server(Windows server 2012) computer say computer1. I have another Windows server(Windows server 2012) PC in which around 10 people are working. Say that pc as computer2. While working in computer2 we used to access chat application from computer1.

Some time I will update the some features of chat application  and replace that in computer1 without any error. Now in order to make latest version of  application available to the users of computer2, all the working users in computer2 has to close and then open the chat application.
This is the procedure which need to be done in order to open the latest version of app,

1. userA and userB are using chat application,
2. userA, userb both closes the application
3. userA, userb opens the app

Here is my problem,

1. userA and userB are using chat application,
2. userA closes the application but userB still kept that app open.
3. userA opens the app, here userA will get old version instead of new version which is available in computer1.

Why this is happening  ? Where windows store the cache ? Is it not possible to make that application to load newer version when a other user is kept open that ?
I know I can follow method1 as solution, but it is very difficult to know that all the users are closed the app so that I can inform again to open it.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the file never actually got updated because User B was holding it open.

To force a file closed on Windows Server, open the Shared Folders snap-in for MMC. Navigate to *Open Files* in the left pane. Find the file in question in the main area, right-click it, and choose *Close Open File*. You'll then be able to update the program.

[image: closing the file]

Note that User B's instance of the program may behave strangely or crash after doing that, since the file it's running from suddenly closed.

Comment: But there no files in Open File window.